# Magento2: Error in data structure: job_id values are mixed

Tags: magento2, import

During import products to magento 2.3.4 after few minutes I get issue:

```
Configure variations for SKU:98010
Configure variations for SKU:98009

In Data.php line 120:

  Error in data structure: job_id values are mixed


import:job:run [<job>...]
```

When I run again import products, then again import some products and get the same issue. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

User has probably figured this out but for anyone looking, this is related to firebear specifically. Firebear called **getJobId()** which should return a single job_id from the table **firebear_importexport_importdata**. However, you have leftover data from a previous job in that table that didn't get removed. **Truncate** the table and you will be fine as that table temporarily holds data during an import job running.